# Swift 4 present view controller black screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm presenting another view controller like this:

```
func goToScreen(id : String) {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id)
    self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem is, there is a cc. 1 second delay between the appearance of the new viewcontroller, and in the meantime the app shows an all black screen. Why is that? It looks really ugly

Answer (score 2):

change status of animation to false while move to next view controller this will remove the delay. Delay happening only because of animation: true.
Use below code to solve your issue

```
self.present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I was inheriting from **UITabBarController** instead of **UIViewController** from the screen I was pushing to.